# How to completely remove header of word press theme "Twenty Nineteen"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to `completely remove the header part` of word press theme in `"Twenty Nineteen"`,how do i do that,i checked on `themes>>customize` ,i didnt find option.I have highlighted below which i want to remove

Thanks In advance
[image: Header which needs to be removed in twenty nineteen wordpress theme]

Comment: you have to override inside functions.php

Comment: to override `functions.php` or any template file of your theme, make sure to use a chid-theme to avoid your custom code to disappear everytime you update the theme. Or else you may use a plugin if you want to keep the master theme clean.

Comment: thank you both ,worked like a charm